# Find out which program requested authentication

Tags: password, users, authentication, gksu, pkexec

I get password prompts like the one below every now and then. Usually they say:

> **Authentication is required to change your own user data**
>   [image]

But I have not requested to do so.

This often happens e.g. when I switch between two user accounts.

How do I find out why I get those dialogues and which program is responsible for them (for maybe filing a bug report)?

Answer (score 1):

All such requests are logged in `/var/log/auth.log` in a format that looks similar to (anything from `polkitd` in there should relate to these forms of authentication request):

```
Apr 23 17:45:09 tester-VirtualBox polkitd(authority=local): Operator of unix-session:c2 successfully authenticated as unix-user:tester to gain TEMPORARY authorization for action org.debian.apt.install-or-remove-packages for system-bus-name::1.89 [/usr/bin/python3 /usr/bin/gnome-language-selector] (owned by unix-user:tester)
```

A failed attempt would look like this:

```
Apr 23 18:00:55 tester-VirtualBox polkitd(authority=local): Operator of unix-session:c2 FAILED to authenticate to gain authorization for action org.debian.apt.install-or-remove-packages for system-bus-name::1.91 [/usr/bin/python3 /usr/bin/gnome-language-selector] (owned by unix-user:tester)
```

So if you wish to filter only accepted or only rejected ones then you would want to use either:

- `cat auth.log | grep "polkitd" | grep "FAILED to authenticate"`
  Or:
- `cat auth.log | grep "polkitd" | grep "successfully authenticated"`

For more information on `polkit` see `man polkit`.